# ngAnimate - both source and target template are visible while animation

Tags: angularjs, animation, ngroute, ng-view

I try to create a simple fade-in fade-out animation using ngAnimate. The animation looks good except that the container of the view contains both the source and the target template while animation.

How can I show the active template only?

```
<html ng-app="testApp" lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/ng-template" id="/page1.html">page1 content</script>
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="/page2.html">page2 content</script>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module('testApp', ['ngRoute','ngAnimate']);
            app.config(function($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider.when('/page1', {templateUrl: '/page1.html'});
                $routeProvider.when('/page2', {templateUrl: '/page2.html'});
            });
        </script>

        <style>
            #container {border: 1px solid black;}   /**the container has double height while animation*/

            #content {-webkit-transition: opacity .2s linear;}  
            #content.ng-enter {opacity:0;}
            #content.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {opacity:0;}
            #content.ng-leave {opacity:1;}
            #content.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {opacity:0;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="content" ng-view></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this one?

Comment: I choose the Blaise's 3rd solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple solutions:

1. Delay the enter animation (`transition-delay`) with the duration of the leave animation
2. Remove either the enter or leave animation
3. Use `#content{position: absolute}` or `#content + #content {margin-top: -$height px}` so that the height of the parent is not affected.

Comment: 1. there is a delay after the original template disappears + doesn't solve the issue
2. doesn't work
3. I would't use absolute position because of the layout of my page

Comment: Then use the `margin-top` variant. You cannot have two elements in your DOM in exactly the same place without doing negative offsetting or absolute positioning.

Comment: Is it possible to have only 1 of the elements in the DOM?